# How to cull attributes before creating a virtus Object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, virtus

I have more attributes in my hash than Virtus has defined in it's class.  I want to cull those attributes inside the virtus model before instantiating it.

```
test_hash = {:x="stuff" , :y ="stuff2", :z="stuff3"}
def myObject
  include Virtus.model
  attribute :x, String
  attribute :y, String
end

myObject.new(test_hash)
```

This fails with a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'z='`
I just want it to silently discard z and still create the object.

I tried overriding the initialize method and inserting a culling method, but that didn't appear to work.  Apparently mass assigning attributes goes through a different pathway during object create?

Best way to go about culling these attributes?

Comment: interesting question, might be worth posting a github issue on virtus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work okay with 1.0.5; which version are you on?

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'virtus'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> class MyObject
irb(main):003:1>   include Virtus.model
irb(main):004:1>   attribute :x, String
irb(main):005:1>   attribute :y, String
irb(main):006:1> end
=> MyObject
irb(main):007:0> hash = { x: 'x', y: 'y', z: 'z' }
=> {:x=>"x", :y=>"y", :z=>"z"}
irb(main):008:0> MyObject.new hash
=> #<MyObject:0x007ff0e3e8d9e8 @x="x", @y="y">
```